# How to load (Python) .py file in HTML

Tags: python, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, python-3.x, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a chart using Python in Visual Studio following a tutorial and when I run the application the console pops up and displays the chart.

This gives me a single `.py` file.

Excellent!

Now... Is there anyway that this can be viewed in a web browser?

Ultimately, I would like to use this with an Angular/.NET project and load this in somehow. I have been searching on ways to do this but I'm not sure what the right terminology is concerning Python.

However, a solution where this can be shown within a Python web app would also be useful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the *.py file is generating a graphic chart ? or a text base ?

Comment: @chenchuk a graphic chart.

Comment: Is this file output supposed to be an image? If so, you're going to want to export it as either an SVG or other image format, Think of the .py file as the executable that might create the actual image.

Comment: @Moe Chughtai, I was hoping of somehow calling this file every time to update the data in the chart, keeping the page data dynamic.